# Updating modelValue in Headless UI Listbox component when options array change

Tags: vue.js, frontend, tailwind-css, headless-ui, vue-sfc

I have a `SelectField` Vue Single File Component which relies on Headless UI Listbox.
It receives current `modelValue` as a prop and emits `update:modelValue` event to update parent's state, as normal:

```
// Selectfield.vue
<script setup>
import {Listbox, ListboxButton, ListboxLabel, ListboxOption, ListboxOptions} from "@headlessui/vue";
...
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: [ Array, String ],
    options: { type: Object }
    ...
</script>

<template>
    <!-- Listbox -->
    <Listbox as="div" :modelValue="modelValue" @update:modelValue="value => $emit('update:modelValue', value)">
    ...
    </Listbox>
</template>
```

As you can see, `options` list is another prop, dynamic from the outside.

I need to keep updated `modelValue` value when `options` change, but I do not know the standard way of doing this. Perhaps using a `watcher` on `options`? Or how could it be made?

Thanks in advance.